# Android Studio OS X: Gradle seems to have no connection to jcenter (?)

Tags: macos, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I only come along Android Development once a year or so, so I don't use Android Studio on a daily basis.

My goal was to build a particular project, but because I got weird errors, I finally decided to:

- Completely Uninstall Android Studio
- Reinstall Android Studio (both 2.2.3 and 2.3, same result)
- Create a simple project using the IDE
- Try to build it

But it does not build

As this may be the best error message, `gradlew task` in the console says:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'HelloAndroid'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
     Required by:
         :HelloAndroid:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
         > org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<init>(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)V

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

You can find the full log with --debug --info --stacktrace [here](https://gist.github.com/below/ae461ff69141624494488fcfc9da4dc8)

I have checked and reinstalled Java 8, tried to find anything blocking in my network settings, of course reinstalled Android Studio and rebooted my machine.

What is the cause of these problems? Or can I find the cause?

EDIT: My build files are the ones generated by Android Studio, I have not manually edited them. `build.gradle`(Project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`build.gradle` (Module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.below.helloandroid"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: How does your build script look like?

Comment: I have updated my post. The build scripts are as they were generated by Android Studio. When I can build something simple, then I can move to the complicated stuff ;)

Comment: Ah, sorry, should have read the error message properly, your build script looks fine. `org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<init>(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)V` is the interesting part. Please re-run with `-s` to get the full stacktrace, it might have further information.

Comment: Have added a link to the full log with --debug --info --stacktrace https://gist.github.com/below/ae461ff69141624494488fcfc9da4dc8 Thanks for looking into this

Comment: can you access https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom?

Comment: Yep. At least with curl I can GET it without any issues

Comment: Your stacktrace shows incompatible http client. 
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<init>(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems strange, as the stacktrace complains about a method not being present that is available in httpclient since 4.4 and the Gradle version 2.14.1 that you are using bundles 4.4.1.

The only thing I could imagine currently is, that you have an older version of httpclient in your Java ext dir and so the class from that older version is used which does not have this method.

Comment: Thank you. Where do I find my Java ext dir? Or how can I make sure only the latest version is being used?

Comment: Add `println System.properties.'java.ext.dirs'` to your build script and you get the locations in the output. But if you didn't place it there yourself, it is unlikely that it is there. Except maybe you put it there and forgot about it.

Comment: Indeed, credit where credit is due. As @below says in his own answer, we could get the project to build by locating some outdated Apache libraries in one of the extension dirs on the classpath. In this case, `~/Library/Extensions` which contained `httpclient-4.3.1`. Never a good idea to put stuff in (almost) global dirs :)

Answer (score 0):

With the help from @Vampire, @Michal and @dscheller I solved the problem by deleting everything (including the http client) in ~/Library/Java/Extensions